# How to attach csv in mutt command using C shell

Tags: html, csv, csh, mutt

Below is the code I tried with html body with out attaching csv file. It is working fine

```
#!/bin/csh
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "status report on" rama@abc.com < mail1.html
```

Below is the code I tried when I am trying to attach csv file. But it's not working properly and getting error as shown below.

```
#!/bin/csh
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "status report on" -a "sum.csv" rama@abc.com < mail1.html

Can't stat rama@abc.com: No such file or directory
rama@abc.com: unable to attach file.
```

May I know what went wrong in above code??

Comment: It seems the sum.csv file does not exist.

Comment: @AliceOualouest, sum.csv file exists in my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your recipient after the attachments, then you must add `--` as a separator.

Check the manual page for mutt:

> ```
>  -a file [...]
>         Attach  a  file  to  your  message  using MIME.  
>         When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient
>         addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1
>         or mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2.   The  -a  option
>         must be placed at the end of command line options.
> ```